# cannot run ros commands

Tags: ros, ros-comm, roscore, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi! whenever i try to run ros commands such as roscore or rosmake, it keeps popping up >>

File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in 
from ros import roslaunch
File "/opt/ros/electric/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/**init**.py", line 55
except roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException as e:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I would b glad if any of you can solve this problem.my default python version is 2.6.6. thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11479/cannot-run-ros-commands/) by [vasp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1198/vasp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2011-10-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-10-10**:
The syntax error would tend to indicate an older, not newer Python.

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-10**:
I just installed Python3.2 (Ubuntu 11.04), ran some ROS stuff with it, and I got an AttributeError exception. So while I agree with Lorenzo that this looks like some sort of Python version conflict, I am unable to reproduce the same error.

**Comment by [Lorenzo Riano](https://answers.ros.org/users/155/lorenzo-riano/) on 2011-10-10**:
I think it's due to a Python 2.6 -3 conflict. Röhling maybe you should post your comment as an answer.

**Comment by [roehling](https://answers.ros.org/users/798/roehling/) on 2011-10-10**:
Are you sure that your ROS binaries actually use Python 2.6? The Syntax Error exception indicates otherwise. Do you have Python 3.x installed?

**Comment by [vasp](https://answers.ros.org/users/1198/vasp/) on 2011-10-09**:
i'm using Ubunthu 10.10 and ros electric package. not only ros core..all the roscommands like rosdep, roswtf also giving me the same error.it was working fine last time. i didnt even update the versions. but since it's not working i tried updating the ubunthu, python version and ros package. but i still hav the same problem.

**Comment by [Mac](https://answers.ros.org/users/127/mac/) on 2011-10-09**:
Tell us more; which sort of system are you on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you sure that your ROS binaries actually use Python 2.6? The Syntax Error exception indicates otherwise. Do you have Python 3.x installed? - Röhling (Oct 10)

I think it's due to a Python 2.6 -3 conflict. Röhling maybe you should post your comment as an answer. - Lorenzo Riano (Oct 10)

I just installed Python3.2 (Ubuntu 11.04), ran some ROS stuff with it, and I got an AttributeError exception. So while I agree with Lorenzo that this looks like some sort of Python version conflict, I am unable to reproduce the same error. - Röhling (Oct 10)

---

Originally posted by [Wim](https://answers.ros.org/users/38/wim/) with karma: 2915 on 2011-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0